# What is catalog in prestodb

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I am reading [this part](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/overview/concepts.html) of the documentation, and I came across this line

> A Presto catalog contains schemas and references a data source via a connector

I really don't understand what catalogs are and how they relate to schemas. Connectors on the other hand sounds understandable enough.

It later then said

> Catalogs are defined in properties files stored in the Presto configuration directory.

So I thought to better understand catalogs and how they relate to schemas, I can take a look at how they are defined. So I went to check the defaults ones and I see

```
bash-4.2# cat jmx.properties
connector.name=jmx
```

So I only see a connector being defined here.

But if I use the `presto-cli` I can list the catalogs by running

```
show catalogs
     -> ;
 Catalog
---------
 jmx
 memory
 system
 tpcds
 tpch
(5 rows)
```

Then I can ask to be shown the schemas in jmx

```
presto> show schemas in jmx;
       Schema
--------------------
 current
 history
 information_schema
(3 rows)

Query 20230607_045934_00006_tbv5p, FINISHED, 1 node
Splits: 19 total, 19 done (100.00%)
[Latency: client-side: 0:04, server-side: 0:04] [3 rows, 47B] [0 rows/s, 12B/s]
```

So it looks like `jmx` does come with some schemas. SO now I am totally confused.

The documentation tells me if I check the catalog definition I will find the schema's defined, I did but did not find any definion, but even though when I run the command to show the schema in a catalog it does contains them

So what exactly are catalog really?

Answer (score -1):

> So it looks like jmx does come with some schemas. SO now I am totally confused.

TBH I'm a bit confused why. Data in Presto is organized in catalogs and schemas. Each schema can contain tables. As for the JMX, for it you can check the [JMX (Java Management Extensions) Connector doc](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/jmx.html):

> The JMX connector provides the ability to query JMX information from all nodes in a Presto cluster. This is very useful for monitoring or debugging

> The JMX connector provides two schemas:
> The first one is `current` that contains every MBean from every node in the Presto cluster.
> ...
> The `history` schema contains the list of tables configured in the connector properties file.

The third one is the "system" schema allowing to query different information about the catalog (I used it to query info about tables and columns for some scripting).

You can use [`SHOW TABLES`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/show-tables.html) to see the tables defined in the schema:

```sql
show tables in jmx.information_schema;
```

Output:

```
      Table
------------------
 applicable_roles
 columns
 enabled_roles
 roles
 schemata
 table_privileges
 tables
 views
```

And then you can query one of the tables, for example:

```sql
 select * from jmx.information_schema.columns limit 1;
```

Output:

| table_catalog | table_schema | table_name | column_name | ordinal_position | column_default | is_nullable | data_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jmx | information_schema | applicable_roles | grantee | 1 | NULL | YES | varchar |

To configure catalog you can add corresponding file in `etc/catalog` for example for JMX docs say:

> To configure the JMX connector, create a catalog properties file `etc/catalog/jmx.properties`

You can have different catalogs using the same connector but with different settings. Catalog can be considered as analog of database on some SQL database server.